# how to programmatically stop video recording in progress in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native, asynchronous, video-recording

I wanted to develop a native module in react-native to record a video and to stop the recording at any time. The problem which I faced is the nativemodule thread blocks once the recording starts and any attempt to call a method in the native module to stop the recording is blocked until the condition set by mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration() or mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize() is fulfilled or I press the back button manually. But, I wanted to stop the recording at any time programmatically without the above conditions being fulfilled. More clarification using a code snippet is as follows:

```
....
startAndStopRecording = () => {
    NativeModules.videoRecordingModule.startRecording(); // Now the recording starts without any problem but the code after this line doesn't execute until the above conditions are fulfilled.
   setTimeout(() => {
       NativeModules.videoRecordingModule.stopRecording(); // this line runs only if the recording reaches the max. duration or max. file size or I press on the back button.
   }, anyPreferredTime);
}
...
```

Is there a way to run the `stopRecording()` statement asynchronously in react-native? Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself and here is what I found out:

**Before the solution:**

on the React-native side, I had a code snippet similar to the one below:

```
....
startAndStopRecording = () => {
    NativeModules.videoRecordingModule.startRecording();  // Line 1
   setTimeout(() => {
       NativeModules.videoRecordingModule.stopRecording(); // Line 2
   }, anyPreferredTime);
}
...
```

And on the native (Java) side, I had the following:

```
@ReactMethod
public void startRecording() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(getCurrentActivity(), VideoRecorder.class);
   getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

My problem was Line 2 didn't execute till the video recording was finished on the Java side. After some troubleshooting, I understood the following (correct me if I am wrong):
  *If you call a method in a native module from react-native (JS) side and that method delegates an intent to start an activity, you can't run subsequent tasks until the started activity finishes.*
As a result, until the started video recording finishes, Line 2 couldn't run.

**My solution:**

The solution which I found is to create android Fragment instead of starting an activity. Now the code is the same in the JS side but on the native side, I have the following and it works as intended and subsequent lines execute while the video recrding is taking place.

```
@ReactMethod
public void startRecording() {   
     FragmentManager manager = activity.getFragmentManager();  // check for deprecation
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
     VideoRecordingFragment fragment = new VideoRecordingFragment();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

And the video recording fragment class looks as follows:

```
public class VideoRecordingFragment extends Fragment implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

.....
.....
}
```